# Facebook scraper cache isn't refreshing

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Around two weeks ago I added some additional og tags to a page so that more images show up when people share the page on Facebook, like so:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.arthackday.net/img/about/Arthackday_About_How-it-works.jpg?zuckerderp=1391735492"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.arthackday.net/img/about/Arthackday_About_Partners.jpg?zuckerderp=1391735492"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.arthackday.net/img/about/Arthackday_About_What-is.jpg?zuckerderp=1391735492"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.arthackday.net/video/berlin_poster.jpg?zuckerderp=1391735492"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.arthackday.net/img/ahd_assets/ahd_logo_black_200px.png"/>
```

However, after two weeks the Facebook scraper "See exactly what the scraper sees" at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.arthackday.net%2Fabout hasn't cleared the cache and shows only one tag from before I added the new ones:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.arthackday.net/img/ahd_assets/ahd_logo_black_200px.png">
```

These are all the things I have tried to force it to refresh. None worked:

- Adding URL parameters to the new images with a new value that changes every time the page is loaded.
- Entering the URL at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/.
- Doing the same while logged into Facebook.
- Doing the same while logged in as an administrator of the Facebook page associated with the site.
- Doing the same on a laptop centered in a pentagram drawn with goat blood (and some chicken blood... I ran out) while holding a voodoo doll resembling Mark Zuckerburg.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: I can't I was awarded a tumbleweed instead of an answer. I vote up correct answers. Anyone?

Comment: What's up with the redirect? '/about' has the extra og:image tags but not '/'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `og:url` tells FB which page to ultimately scrape. Try changing it to `http://www.arthackday.net/about`.

The og properties/values you're seeing in the debugger are matching what's on the current `og:url` value (`http://www.arthackday.net/`). I'm guessing since the final 'Redirect Path' has `og:url` in the left column, that's the reason why it's going there.

I've never set `og:url` to anything other than the current page, so I may be off. Worth a shot, though.

Comment: Yes, as open graph should work, but this won't work on facebook, maybe only with a one time clicked url. It seems that they use cache but they don't provide way to refresh, including while using this tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/